# Mongodb sort by sum of keys

Tags: mongodb

I have a json document

```
{
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5715c4bbac530eb3018b456a"),
       "content_id" : "5715c4bbac530eb3018b4569",
       "views" : NumberLong(200),
       "likes" : NumberLong(100),
       "comments" : NumberLong(0)
   },
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5715c4bbac530eb3018b4568"),
       "content_id" : "5715c4bbac530eb3018b4567",
       "views" : NumberLong(300),
       "likes" : NumberLong(200),
       "comments" : NumberLong(0)
   },
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5715c502ac530ee5018b4956"),
       "content_id" : "5715c502ac530ee5018b4955",
       "views" : NumberLong(500),
       "likes" : NumberLong(0),
       "comments" : NumberLong(200)
   }
}
```

How can we sort the document order by SUM("views", "likes", "comments")

something like in mysql

```
SELECT SUM(key1, key2, key3) AS key
FROM document
ORDER BY key
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use the aggregate method in order to first calculate sum and then sort your data using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do a projection to obtain the sum of all the likes, views and comments, then sort based on that sum. I am considering group by content_id if is needed in the second snippet

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $project : { "_id" : "$content_id", "total" : { $add : [ "$likes", "$views", "$comments"]}}},
    { $sort : { "total" : 1 }}
])
```

If you need a group operation if content_id can be duplicated

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $project : { "_id" : "$content_id", "total" : { $add : [ "$likes", "$views", "$comments"]}}},
    { $group : { "_id" : "$_id" , totalPerId : { $sum : "$total" }}},
    { $sort : { "total" : 1 }}
])
```

Based on your test data, you will get:

```
{ "_id" : "5715c502ac530ee5018b4955", "totalPerId" : NumberLong(700) }
{ "_id" : "5715c4bbac530eb3018b4567", "totalPerId" : NumberLong(500) }
{ "_id" : "5715c4bbac530eb3018b4569", "totalPerId" : NumberLong(300) }
```